# convert javascript from onclick to onhover

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the code in this tutorial to create a list of categories that people click on to navigate to the appropriate page.  How can I change this so that the menu opens when a user hover over on a desktop and remains with a click on a mobile?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_dropdown_categories -- Dropdown without a submit button

My Code

```
if (isset($cat_id2->term_id)) { 
    $selected = $cat_id2->term_id; 
} else {  
    $selected = -1; 
}

$args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => 'Browse All Listings',
    'show_option_none'   => '',
    'orderby'            => 'NAME', 
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'hide_empty'         => 1, 
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'exclude'            => 1,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'selected'           => $selected,
    'hierarchical'       => 1, 
    'name'               => 'cat',
    'id'                 => '',
    'class'              => 'postform',
    'depth'              => 1,
    'tab_index'          => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'hide_if_empty'      => false,
);

wp_dropdown_categories( $args );

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
        else { location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/listing/"; }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;

</script>
```

Comment: try to change this line dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;  to dropdown.onmouseover = onCatChange link for your refernce http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: This would all be made more simple by using CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))
    check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check;
}
```

The function above checks if the user agent is on a mobile device. Now with this you can update your code like:

```
if(mobilecheck()){
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
}else{
   dropdown.onmouseenter = onCatChange;
}
```